# Corona Lua calculate in seconds between 2 dates

Tags: date, time, lua, coronasdk

I have 2 dates from a pickerWheel, into an os.time table. I wanna calculate the difference between those 2 in seconds. I already have something but after doing the math my own, it aint so accurate I think.

```
local currentDate = os.date( '*t' )
local setTime = os.time{ year = myApp.y, month = myApp.m, day = myApp.d, hour = myApp.h, min = myApp.min, sec = 0 }
local endTime = os.time{ year = myApp.ey, month = myApp.em, day = myApp.ed, hour = myApp.h, min = myApp, sec = 0 }

local differenceInSec = endTime - setTime
local days = differenceInSec / 86400
local hours = days % 1 * 24
local minutes = hours % 1 * 60
local seconds = math.floor( minutes % 1 * 60 + 0.5 )
```

For example, setTime is 1-11-2015 and endTime is 10-11-2015 (DD-MM-YYYY). It return 776460, but it should return about 864000 right? Is there something I did wrong or someone could help me out?

Comment: Difference between `Nov 1` and `Nov 10` is 9 days, not 10.

Comment: Have you ever used math.fmod?